# Which is more performance efficient on creating object with jQuery? Using jquery object or raw HTML string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to know, which is preferred on creating DOM?

Let's say I want to create and put some element

```
$('#someDiv').append(html);
```

1. Raw HTML string

   ```
   let html = '<span class="someClass">John Doe</span>';
   ```
2. jQuery object

   ```
   let html = $('<span></span>').addClass('someClass').text('John Doe');
   ```
3. Or any other method I am not aware of?

Thank you for your kindness

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
let html = $('<span>', {
    "class": "someClass",
    text: "John Doe"
});
```

This only calls one function and requires no DOM parsing (jQuery recognizes a single tag as a special case).

Comment: Oh cool, this was new to me. So how do you nest multiple jquery created object?

Comment: Use the `html:` property: `$("<obj1>", { html: $("<obj2>", { ... }), ...})`